# Opencart 2.0.1.1 - product/search.php, cant figure out where to add extra functionality

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I think the correct file to alter is `catalog/controller/product/search.php` to add extra functionality to search. Basically I wanted to grab a specific attribute that product have and run the array of results through. So I have the next difficulties:

```
$search = $someInput; // Where do i get search input? 
$arraySearch = compact($search);  // Compact it to array
$resultsArray = SELECT desired_attribute FROM product_table; // Insert my desired query, where do I do that? Is there some quick way, like get->?
```

> $filteredResult = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $resultsArray->desired_attribute'); // Filter it to numbers only.
>
> array_intersect($arraySearch, $filteredResult); // find product based on this intersect.

May I have some ideas? It's just Opencart is really horribly documented. This is very easy with frameworks.

Comment: read this tutorial (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru), it's for OC 1.5.x but will be very helpful to you

Comment: ***Where do i get search input?*** `$this->request->get['key']`

Comment: ***Insert my desired query...*** `$this->db->query('quey here')`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I managed to accomplish it by searching deep in model code. The queries are one huge bus there. The info you provided is really useful. Thanks a lot!